# Is the sentence incomplete without the use of There at the end of the sentence? What is the purpose?

Tags: adverb-placement

**[SOURCE](https://learnenglishteens.britishcouncil.org/ar/magazine/life-around-world/i-have-two-sisters-let-me-tell-you-about-them)**   (British Council *LearnEnglish Teens*)

I was doing some reading on a web site. Here is the sentence that I am thinking why they have to put the adverb (There) at the ending of the sentence.

> My biggest sister is actually the smallest...
>   She also loves horses. When she was younger,   she used to go to a local farm regularly to help look after the donkeys and horses **there**.

Is sentence incomplete without the use of There?

Can I just say

> she used to go to a local farm regularly to help look after the
>   donkeys and horses.

What is the purpose of using There?

Comment: "There" is anaphoric to "a local farm". It's functioning as an adjunct, i.e. an optional item, so it's a matter of personal choice whether it should be included. You might say "there" was redundant, though, since it's clear that the donkeys and horses are located at the local farm where she used to go.

Comment: Thank you, BillJ! Your comment is helpful, please write it as an answer. Yours can help me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not incorrect to put **there** at the end of that sentence. Without **there** the listener (reasonably) infers that the horses and donkeys are there.  The purpose of **there** is merely to say that the horses and donkeys were there :)